# Difference in dates using sqldf in R

Tags: r, date, sqldf

I have two columns in a data frame where I need to calculate the difference in time. The data is the local PD data from open data of cities. One column is below

```
TimeDispatch             
01/01/2011 12:00:37 AM   

TimeArrive
01/01/2011 12:21:31 AM
```

Also the TimeArrival as a few missing values as every dispatch does not need the cops to arrive.

I am trying to find the difference using sqldf in R but it says this error

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement, bind.data) : 
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) :
  Closing result set with pending rows
```

Any help guys?

Comment: Is it necessary to do it with the help of `sqldf`?

Comment: Can you please post the query you are using?

Comment: total$TimeDispatched <- as.POSIXlt(strptime(total$TimeDispatch, format= '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'))
total$TimeArrived <- as.POSIXlt(strptime(total$TimeArrive, format= '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:S'))
total$diff <- difftime(total$TimeDispatched, total$TimeArrived, units = c(auto))                                                              q2 <- sqldf('select avg(diff) as Avg_Arrival_time from total where diff is not null group by PoliceDistrict')     The issue is that I need to later on group them with SQL and sqldx is not good with POSIXct date

Comment: You can also group them without using `sqldf` as well.

Comment: Thank you Kunal, I actually solved it. It was actually simple. After the conversion, I just used an as.integer function and then used the group by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found the answer. Just convert the difftime variable to an integer using `as.integer()`. I read numerous blogs and I could not find the answer anywhere so I am posting the answer for future reference

Answer (score 3):

From the comments to the question, the problem is not how to calculate the difference bewteen two times using sqlite.  The times have already been differenced before sending them to sqlite and the problem is that the resulting `"difftime"` class column is converted to numeric when it is sent to sqlite and when it is retrieved back to R, `sqldf` does not know how to convert that number back to a `"difftime"` class object because it does not know which units to use.

Here is a self contained example to illustrate:

```
library(sqldf)

now <- Sys.time()
now2 <- now + 1
dif <- difftime(now2, now)
DF <- data.frame(dif)

sqldf("select * from DF")
## Error in asfn(rs[[i]]) : need explicit units for numeric conversion
```

There are several approaches to this:

1) do not use a `"difftime"` object in the first place.  Use the number of seconds or minutes or whatever as a numeric variable:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(dif = as.numeric(dif))
sqldf("select * from DF1")

##   dif
## 1   1
```

2) perform the differencing in SQL rather than in R so that a `"difftime"` column is not created in the first place:

```
DF2 <- data.frame(now, now2)
sqldf("select now2 - now as dif from DF2")

##   dif
## 1   1
```

3) use `sqldf(..., method = "raw")` to prevent it from trying to convert back to `"difftime"` class:

```
sqldf("select * from DF")

##   dif
## 1   1
```

4) make sure that the original `"difftime"` column is renamed in the output so that it cannot associate it with the original `"difftime"` column and so the heuristic that assigns classes will not try to convert it.

```
sqldf("select dif as dif2 from DF")

##   dif2
## 1    1
```

5) Use the `name__class` method of sqldf (note the double underscore to specify the class to convert to:

```
sqldf("select dif as dif__numeric from DF", method = "name__class")

##   dif
## 1   1
```