# Difference between dates in SQLDF in R

Tags: r, datetime, sqldf

I am using the R package SQLDF and am having trouble finding the number of days between two date time variables. The variables `ledger_entry_created_at` and `created_at` are Unix Epochs and when I try to subtract them after casting to `julianday`, I return a vector of `NA`'s.

I've taken a look at [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684747/difference-in-dates-using-sqldf-in-r) and didn't find it useful since my answer to be given in SQL for reasons that are outside the scope of this question.

If anyone could help me figure out a way to do this inside SQLDF I would be grateful.

[image]

EDIT:

```
    SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', l.created_at, 'unixepoch') ledger_entry_created_at, 
      l.ledger_entry_id, l.account_id, l.amount, a.user_id, u.created_at
  FROM ledger l
  LEFT JOIN accounts a
  ON l.account_id = a.account_id
  LEFT JOIN users u
  ON a.user_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: These dates look like regular text timestamps/dates to me, _not_ UNIX epoch timestamps.

Comment: Please include the R code you are using to query.

Comment: The variable `ledger_entry_created_at` was created with the following code invoked inside `SQLDF`: `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', l.created_at, 'unixepoch') ledger_entry_created_at`. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what this returns?

Comment: If you have two UNIX timestamps, and you want days between them, then why not just subtract and convert seconds difference to days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is trivial, but if you already have two UNIX timestamps, and you want to find out how many days have elapsed between them, you can simply take the difference in seconds (their original unit), and convert to days, e.g.

```
SELECT
    (l.created_at - u.created_at) / (3600*24) AS diff
    -- any maybe other columns here
FROM ledger l
LEFT JOIN accounts a
    ON l.account_id = a.account_id
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON a.user_id = u.user_id;
```

I don't know why your current approach is failing, as the timestamps you have in the screen capture should be valid inputs to SQLite's `julianday` function.  But, again, you may not need such a complicated route to get the result you want.