# R SQLDF difference between two timestamps in days?

Tags: r, sqldf

I am using the SQLDF package in which I need to get the difference between timestamps converted to different formats such as seconds and dates. I cannot find any timestamp object in the documentation, tried this suggestion  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307385/164148), malfunctioning, so

### **How can you calculate the difference between timestamps with SQLDF -package in R?**

```
> sqldf("SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '2017-10-10 10:10:10')-  strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '2019-01-01 01:01:01') AS timestamp2")

timestamp2
1       -2


> sqldf("SELECT '2017-10-10 10:10:10'-'2019-01-01 01:01:01'")

'2017-10-10 10:10:10'-'2019-01-01 01:01:01'
1                                          -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion might have to do with confounding the `strftime()` function which exists in R with a function by the same name which also exists in SQLite.  Keeping in mind that the `sqldf` package will run whatever is inside your query string as SQLite code, if you wanted the difference in seconds, you should be using:

```
SELECT
    strftime('%s', '2017-10-10 10:10:10') -
    strftime('%s', '2019-01-01 01:01:01');
```

This returns `-38674251`, which corresponds to the second timestamp being about 1.25 years later than the first timestamp.

Comment: This page describes SQLite's time and date functions: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html  Also note that if you use a different backend to sqldf then there will be other functions.

Comment: Is the only way to get the difference in other units dividing seconds by different factors? Eg. ```sqldf("SELECT (strftime('%s', '2017-10-10 10:10:10')-  strftime('%s', '2019-01-01 01:01:01'))/3600/24 AS timestamp2")``` returning difference in days.

Comment: In the H2 backend `datediff('day', date1, date2)` can be used.  See http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I have all data actually in CSV, but for SQL practise, I want some SQL package that allows me to run all things with most functionalities (I usually do this in datatable very well, but now trying to do everything in SQL). How would you do that? I am finding missing commands in SQLDF very limiting thing. Is H2 somehow better?

Comment: It supports sqlite, h2, mysql and postgresql.  postgresql is the most powerful of them but you have to install and configure it properly.  sqlite is the default and h2 only requires that you install java which is very easy to do.  I have generally found sqlite does most of what I need but h2 is better for dates and times.